# UIImagePickerController exception : "Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera"

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

what is wrong with this? I really don't understand some important parts for UIImagePickerController....

here's the source:

```
     UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;        
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
[imagePickerController release];
```

Can't I open the photo library?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're using the photo library, do you need to set `cameraCaptureMode`?

Comment: Other properties will cause similar failures, e.g. cameraViewTransform

Answer (score 15):

Maybe not in your case but when you initalize your UIImagePickerController object,  FIRST you need to set your source type before setting any other properties otherwise you get the same error.

```
let imagePickerController =  UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode =   
UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo
imagePickerController.cameraDevice = .Front
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = true;
imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = false;
imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = false;
imagePickerController.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 10):

my problem was that i set camera device to `.front` before setting `imagePicker.sourceType = .camera` and obviously it caused crash.
so i changed my code from :

```
 imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
 imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
```

to this :

```
imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
```

and problem solved :)

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact same exception, however I wasn't using an instance of UIImagePickerController control, instead I was showing a web page inside of a UIWebView that had an input w/ HTML Media Access attributes to enable camera access.

The problem is that it seems the UIWebView does not handle the HTML Media Access attributes properly. I noticed that the spec on these attributes changed a few times over time, so while it seemed like valid html and works on safari on the device, it doesn't work on pages rendered using UIWebView.

Bad:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Good:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
```

The exception immediately went away and taking a picture works. This seems to be new to iOS 10 or 11 as it was existing code and didn't blow up in the past.

Comment: You are a hero!

Answer (score 3):

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {

            imagePickerController.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        } else {
            imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [imagePickerController release];
}
else {
    // do stuff ///....Alert 
}
```